# IdentityServe4 authentication API

Tags: authentication, identityserver4

I have been working on IdentityServer4. I currently have web client, in which uses the IS Quickstart. Now, I want to have an authentication API for my mobile client soon.

Basically, the authentication API should work like this:

1. Gets username and password credential
2. Authenticate using IS
3. Will return to bearer token

What I've done so far is for web client. In which, as mentioned uses the IS Quickstart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the hybrid flow. Check samples in https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples

But if you want to have your own login screen, then you can use resource owner password grant instead

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/2_ResourceOwnerPasswords

Comment: Yup! I used the ResourceOwnerPasswor. Thank you